# oracle: select * from tab for other types?

Tags: oracle, sys

I can do a

```
select * from tab;
```

and get a list of tables (and apparently views) - are there similar views set up for other objects, such as sequences, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are (ALL_OBJECTS, ALL_TABLES, ALL_SEQUENCES, ...)

All of them are documented in the manual:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/toc.htm

Comment: Just beat me to it. There is even a view for it. select view_name from all_views
where view_name like 'ALL%';